# PHP Prepared Statements login form

Tags: php, mysql

I have been coding a login script in PHP using prepared statements however I can't get it to work, can anyone point out why this isn't working?

Whenever I log in all I get is the "Statement failed!".

```
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

    //Sanitize the POST values
$login = clean($_POST['login']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

$query = $dbconn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE login=? AND passwd=?");
$query -> bind_param("ss", $login, $password);

if($query->execute() == true) {
    $query -> bind_result($result);
    $query -> fetch();
    if($result){
            $member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_IS_ADMIN'] = $member['admin'];
            session_write_close();
            echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
            echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
            echo "Test!";
            exit();
    }else{
            echo "Statement failed";
    }
}
/* Close statement */
$query -> close();
```

In config.php there is the following:

```
$dbconn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'bookingsystem');
```

And the database structure for the users looks like this:

```
`members` (`member_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `login`, `passwd`, `admin`) VALUES
(1, 'Steve', 'Stone', 'Admin', '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99', 1);
```

Comment: I wouldn't post your MD5 password hashes.

Comment: It's just the word "password" lol, otherwise I wouldn't have :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual on [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and
>   prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch().

You are binding one variable but you are selecting 6 columns. You need to bind all 6 columns to a variable and then inside the condition, you do not have to fetch another row as you have already done that and the results from your fetch will be available in your variables.

You should also check for the return value of `fetch`, not `$result` or any of the other variables.